# How do I run a rails command command from a shell script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sh

Say I wanted to run 'User.all.each{|u| u.destroy}' from a shell script called killallusers.sh. How can I call Rails console commands from the shell or from an executable script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either write it as a [Rake task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rake), or use [Rails "runner"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner).

Inside your shell script put the appropriate rake or runner command.

Comment: @brojsimpson, if that answered your question, reward the answerer by accepting the answer: click the checkmark beside the answer.